# My Android project has duplicated declarations between Enum and string.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, enums

I have String arrays to use for `Spinner` or such.

```
<string-array name="Animal">
    <item >Cat</item>
    <item >Dog</item>
    <item >Rabbit</item>
    <item >Bird</item>
</string-array>
```

I have a container class to contain values users input or select from `Spinner`. The member variables are mostly primitives or `Enum`.

```
public class Container {
    protected int index;
    protected int age;
    protected String name;
    protected Animal pet;
}
```

This is how one of the Enum classes are defined (Note this is a simpler version, and in my actual code, there are some more methods or variables, and each Enum instance is upper case, like CAT).

```
public enum Animal {
    Cat, Dog, Rabbit, Bird,     
}
```

As you see, I'm virtually repeating the same thing in `Enum` and XML. That isn't really good according to DRY. Which should I remove, and how should?

At this point, I lean toward keeping `Enum`, since it's functionally more versatile than XML, and no less maintainable. The only possible problem I might be concerned about is its performance. They might require more memory, and some extra coding work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplication, you should keep the Enum, and then you populate programmaticaly the spinner using `for(Animal animal:Animal.values()) {...}`.

You may use the Enum name as a key to retrieve a localized label or things like that.